# Pymongo Inserted Ids When BulkWriteError occurs

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, unique-index

I know that we can get [inserted_ids](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertManyResult.inserted_ids) of documents inserted by simply accessing [pymongo.results.InsertManyResult](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertManyResult) returned by [insert_many](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) operation

```
>>> o = db.collection.insert_many([{"hash": "abcde"}, {"hash": "efgh"}], ordered=False)
>>> o.inserted_ids
   [ObjectId('5f5280fdca7d7735e9dcbb85'), ObjectId('5f5280fdca7d7735e9dcbb86')]
```

But Let's consider we have a `unique index` field (let's say `"hash"`) on above collection and now I insert two more records with one having **duplicate** unique field that is already inserted which would lead to an expected **Exception** [BulkWriteError](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/errors.html?highlight=BulkWriteError#pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError)

```
>>> try:
        o = db.collection.insert_many([{"hash": "efgh"}, {"hash": "ijk"}], ordered=False)
    except BulkWriteError as e:
        print(e.details)
    
    {'nInserted': 1,
     'nMatched': 0,
     'nModified': 0,
     'nRemoved': 0,
     'nUpserted': 0,
     'upserted': [],
     'writeConcernErrors': [],
     'writeErrors': [{'code': 11000,
                     'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: '
                               'db.collection index: hash_1 dup key: { : "efgh" }',
                     'index': 0,
                     'op': {'_id': ObjectId('5f52814381c45515348fd36b'),
                            'hash': 'efgh'}}]}
```

But my question is can we get inserted ids of documents that were successfully inserted (i.e shown by `'nInserted'`) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pymongo get inserted id's even with duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263513/pymongo-get-inserted-ids-even-with-duplicate-key-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. See my answer to [Pymongo get inserted id's even with duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263513/pymongo-get-inserted-ids-even-with-duplicate-key-error/63264630#63264630) which is a similar type of question.

Comment: seems like there is no other way ... I had already seen this thread you have shared and would not prefer to go back & query again to find new inserted ids ....was expecting something different , but looks like there is no other way ....So just accepting this answer to mark this question closed.